# How to install storage engine ARCHIVE in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have one instance of Google Cloud SQL(first generation) and i need to install ARCHIVE storage engine because i need to store some historical data on one table.
When i'am trying to create the table, or alter the table:
`ALTER table audit engine=ARCHIVE`
 the console gave me the following error: 
`Error Code: 1286. Unknown storage engine 'ARCHIVE'`
`INSTALL PLUGIN`  is not working as this  is also written in documentation. MySql server version installed is 5.6. Any ideas how to install/activate that storage engine on a table?

Comment: You can't. Only InnoDB and MyISAM are supported in Cloud SQL. I couldn't find an official statement (well the FAQ says InnoDB and MyISAM are the options and InnoDB is strongy recommended, see https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#innodb) so i'm posting this as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

@konqi is correct, you can't use the ARCHIVE engine with Cloud SQL. As it's non-transactional, it means there's no crash recovery support, meaning you could lose data in the event of the host machine going down for some reason. We would really like that to not happen, so the ARCHIVE engine is disabled.